# How the form_Valid function works in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

What is this form object on the return line,is it the form object recieved by the submission of a form ? . and since we are returning it with return super().form_valid(form).
can it be accessed like context variables ? from the template represented by the success_url .also form_valid  points to success_url , since were doing super() , shouldnt it point to the success_url of the parent class. but why does it go to the success_url of ContactView.

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.send_email()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is this `form` object on the return line?

`form` is the `ContactForm` instance that Django constructed to validate the POST request. You can thus for example obtain cleaned data from the form with:

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.send_email()
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The `FormView` will thus construct a `ContactForm` with `request.POST` and `request.FILES`, and check `form.is_valid()`. If it is, it will call `form_valid` with this form instance.

> since were doing `super()`, shouldnt it point to the success_url of the parent class.

**No**. `super()` is a proxy-object that will move up the MRO and thus call the parent method, but that parent method is [implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L55-L57):

> ```
>     def form_valid(self, form):
>         """If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL."""
>         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
> ```

The `self` object is however still a `ContactView` object, so `self.get_success_url()` will return the `success_url`.

Often however, [**`reverse_lazy`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) is used. That way you can provide the *name* of the view, and Django can automatically calculate the URL:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('name-of-thanks-view')
```

Comment: thankyou and also in the code of def form_valid(self, form):
 u shared above from github , there is no code inside the function to handle the form . is that code like a guide? if not how does that function figure out that the form object is vallid.

Comment: @dickshant69: in a `FormView`, the form is indeed not handled, that should be done by the user of the `FormView`, so you can for example send a mail like you did. Two popular newphews are [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) and [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView). These work on `ModelForm`s and thus create or update a record.

Comment: How do I get the object in `def form_valid(self, form):`? I have tried `self.object` it returned **None**, I also tried `self.get_object()` it gave me the error **AttributeError: Generic detail view MyCreateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf**.

Comment: @AnonymousUser: `form.instance`.